# Not getting correct output Function not working

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to write a code that will take a number that the user inputted and create an inverted triangle like:
8 6 4 2 0 on the first line,
6 4 2 0 on the second line,
4 2 0 on the third line,
2 0 on the fourth line,
0 on the last line.
My nested for loops worked in a previous code that was in the main not in a function, but I decided I wanted to create a function that when called would run through the loops. However, something in my code isn't right since now I don't get an inverted triangle. I just get 0 and I think that's because my return is 0. I'm not sure if I'm writing my function incorrectly or if it's something else.
Please help. Thank you

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int row(int num)
{
    int number;
    int decreasedNumber;
    
    for(int i = number; i >= 0; i -= 2)
    {
        decreasedNumber = i;
        
        for(int j = decreasedNumber; decreasedNumber >= 0; decreasedNumber -=2)
        {
            cout << decreasedNumber << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    
    //Prompting the user to enter a number and collect that input
    cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> number;
    
    cout << row(number);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accepting `num` as a parameter to `row`, but never using it. Also, you are using `number`, but never initializing it. Instead, it seems you want `number` to be the parameter to the function, instead of a local variable.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8xWcKM).

Also, the variable `j` is never used in the loop, so you should just remove it.

Also, please don't use `using namespace std;`, it's a bad habit that you should avoid.

Comment: I thought for nested for loop you needed to use different initializers like i for the outer and j for the inner. Also, you don't have to have initialize anything in the inner loop? Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding my issue what that my parameters weren't right?

Comment: @TianaChargin Yes, your parameter was not getting used. See the demo link for how the `j` can be removed. The `for` loops don't have to have an initializing statement if it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `number` as the initial value of `i`.

`number` is uninitialized and its value is indeterminate.

Instead of `number`, you should use the argument `num` as the initial value of `i`.